# An example of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is there an example of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfying

$$a_n \to 0 \ (n \to \infty)$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{kn}}{k^2} \to \infty \ (n \to \infty)$$

?

Answer (score 2):

No, of course, there isn't. $a_n \to 0 \ (n \to \infty)$ implies that $a_n$ is bounded, $|a_n|\le A$, so $\displaystyle \left|\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{a_{kn}}{k^2}\right|\le\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{A}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2A}6$ for any $n$, naturally.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n\to 0$ then the tail of the series $\sum\frac{|a_n|}{k^2}$ is bounded above by $\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$ so it converges absolutely. Any subsequence is also absolutely convergent, such as $\sum\frac{a_{kn}}{k^2}$

Comment: That's not the sum in question. The series is evaluated at the $k\cdot n$ term.

Comment: @eranreches ah yes, I missed that. Thanks. I don't think that changes the answer though.